# What is the song played in episode 492 at 8:30

Tags: naruto, music

There is a song played at around 8:30 in episode 492, which I have not heard of yet, but I really like. Is this an unreleased OST, or was it released in one of the movies? It would really help if somebody could answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the track your looking for is called Memories, and I think it's actually from the first Naruto, not Shippuden. I looked high and low man, and I finally found it lol

Answer (score 0):

It's an unreleased OST. There are many OSTs that were left out from the 3 OST albuns. I've searched in multiple youtube channels for that specific one and I didn't find it.

You could send a private message via youtube to one of those guys that are constantly publishing those unreleased OST in their channels.

Comment: Yeah, I tend to follow the music closely so I'm not surprised that it is unreleased. However, in the most recent episode (493), they used a remake of "Ultimate Secrets". I think that they're either gathering material for Boruto, or preparing for a final album

Comment: From what I read, there will be no more OST albuns. And for the Boruto OST, I seriously doubt they will use this OST. They will probably make a new one.

Comment: That is most likely the case, but it does seem a bit odd to make these new OST's so close towards the end of Shippuden